# How do I create a table in PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I tried to create a table in the "app" database, but got this error:

```
app=# CREATE TABLE users;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: LINE 1: CREATE TABLE users;
                                  ^
```

The columns are defined in `models.py` which is why I don't create them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not create the tables in PostgreSQL, SQLAlchemy will create the table (and the columns) for you.  All you need to do is create the *database*, which you have done.  To create the tables with Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

---

To address the error (although as stated above you should not do this), it is because that is not a full `CREATE TABLE` expression.  You need to specify zero or more columns for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case **forgot to import my Model class** and code 
run without any error:).

If you call `create_all()` on interactive mode please ensure that you import particular Model class.

Note: Every time you make a change on Model class restart ipython.